# How to update a Sharepoint List item through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, ms-office

I have a Microsoft Sharepoint list that is used by multiple people and often times all at once. Everyone on the team submits requests via a Form. A certain set of agents go in, update a field within the submission that says that changes from "pending" to "reviewing" the submission. Then, when they're done, they update the status to "completed" so that everyone know's to disregard since it's completed. All that is fine and dandy. What I would like to do is use a VBA Macro that is already established, and have a button within the Macro that automatically updates the status of the first submission it sees that's in the "pending" status to "reviewing" and then they can click a second button once they're done, to move it to "completed". Is this possible?

Is it possible to update a specific column within an submission on a Sharepoint List through Excel VBA. If so, can someone point me in the direction for help?

Comment: So this is a loaded question. What is the data source of the sharepoint item bound to the form? There are also tons of articles about this already, try researchign more

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this and see if it works?

```
Private Sub CreateList()
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim RowCtr As Integer
    RowCtr = 1
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder("http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/Forms/") '<=Variable Location
    For Each f In folder.Files
       Cells(RowCtr, 1).Value = f.Name
       RowCtr = RowCtr + 1
    Next f
End Sub
```

I don't have access to SharePoint now; I can't test it.

Comment: Is this a row counter? If so, that's not exactly what I'm looking for....